# Output Paragraph values instead of the Paragraph IDs in a View REST export?

Tags: views, 8

I have a View with a REST export display (image attached) that has some indexed field values from Search API.

The highlighted portion, `authors`, is a Paragraph field. Instead of the entity ID pointing to the Paragraph, how can I output a JSON object per delta with the field value?

Note, I am not using JSON:API (and cannot). Also, this is a Search API DB (and eventually Solr) based index, so 'Entity' mode cannot be used (and thus, no custom Normalizer).

What can I hook into, or what class can I create, to change how the Paragraph is being included in the result output? I thought about using a custom field formatter, but that seems like a lot of work just to output JSON data (classes, theme hooks, twig etc).

[image: Example output]

Comment: Not sure if it also applies to  `indexed field` values but with regular fields I have successfully extended `FormatterBase` to create `FieldFormatter` https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-0

Comment: But what about returning JSON only, _not_ a render array?

Comment: While selecting the fields in your search index can't you keep expanding through the referenced entities until you find your specific fields you want to index. (I'm guessing you're currently just indexing the entity reference field for your author and not the fields on that author entity) Then once you've got those fields indexed they should be available within views to show as values (Again assuming your view is based on the search index entity type)

Comment: Right, so, there must be a way then to tell a specific field how to be included to a view. I think I am looking for a field formatter that can return a JSON structure, or something similar.

Comment: Ah I see sorry you want more than just 1 field from the authors paragraph to be displayed in the authors item. Could a twig tpl file for your views field work? Might be abit messy but looks like twig has a json_encode option https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/json_encode.html

Comment: @kevin I am returning `$element[$delta] = ['#type' => 'markup', '#markup' => $somevalue];`

Comment: That is still a string

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about using a custom field formatter, but that seems like a
>   lot of work just to output JSON data

**No Code Solution:**

Install [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)

Create a new View, "User view" in this case (does not to be a REST view).

- Add user fields you want to show.
- Add Contextual filter of ID

  - When adding, scroll down to the "More" section. [Checkmark allow multiple values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szjrt.png).

Go to your Rest View

- Add field of "View", select the view you added above.

  - For contextual filter, use the replacement pattern for your author's field.